# Accessing boolean in Firebase

Tags: javascript, json, angular, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on a NativeScript app with Firebase. **I have to display featured elements based on their status in the firebase array object**. The status is

```
featured= true.
```

I want to filter directly in my function's url using query params (That's without using Headers in the http request).

Here is a sample of the firebase data structure

```
dishes
    0
        category: 
        "mains"
        comments
        description: 
        "A unique combination of Indian Uthappam (pancak..."
        featured: "true"
        id: 0
        image:  "https://www.inspiredtaste.net/wp-content/upload..."
        label: "Hot"
        name:  "Uthappizza"
        price:  "4.99"
```

and here is my typscript angular based method:

```js
 getFeaturedDish(): Observable<Dish> {
    return this.http.get<Dish[]>(baseURL + 'dishes.json' /**query placeholder */).pipe(map(dishes => dishes[0]))
      .pipe(catchError(this.processHTTPMsgService.handleError));
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To filter your structure on `featured` being `"true"`, you'd use:

```
dishes.json?orderBy="featured"&equalTo="true"
```

Don't forget the double quotes around `"true"` as you are storing a string value, and not a boolean.

Also see the Firebase documentation on [filtering data with the REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/retrieve-data#section-rest-filtering).

Comment: I visited the website of firebase and that worked fine. Thank you so much Frank ! Highly appreciated. I am struggling with dynamic id loading for a while now. It would be great if you could make some insights. In my firebase this is the address of the object [name]firebaseio.com/dishes/3. And here is my method                                
     getDish(id: number): Observable<Dish> {
    return this.http.get<Dish>(baseURL +'dishes.json/' + /** id of my object upon clicking*/)
      .pipe(catchError(this.processHTTPMsgService.handleError));
  }.

Comment: I am totally new to firebase. I would be happy if you could comment.PS: The id of the object is fetched via nativescript routing